# Blender 2.8: Join doesn't work

Tags: append

In Blender 2.8 I tried to join several objects together using CTRL + J: function doesn't work and can't find it elsewhere. I want to join into 1 object so that I can append that file to a new one and not have to import several objects. Anyone know how to join in 2.8?

[Link to .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YoTvvX6LuujOGu71B7qqHWBru2Z7l5Hy)

Comment: This should work... Please upload your file so we could investigate.

Comment: FWIW Ctrl-J works fine for me on 2.80.45  How about F3 and search for "Join" does it work for you there?

Comment: @batFINGER: nope, nothing comes up for 'Join' in the search panel...

Comment: @Jackdaw: post now has link to .blend file, thanks

Comment: @batFINGER: thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: Work for me... selecting all objects in object mode and CTRL-J. Do a Load Factory Settings... it might work.

Comment: @Jackdaw: appreciate you investigating, but just tried that and it didn't work. Downloaded the most recent Blender build as well, and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The railings are one sided. Mostly the face normals are facing inwards (see the little blue lines in the screen shots below) which may be a problem when using this model in a game engine. The railings will appear transparent when viewed from outside.

[image]

To veiw the model as it will likely appear in a game engine then enable the **Backface Culling** option in the Shading menu.

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation- you're right, I'm not familiar with face normals. This is a different model I'm using just for fun in Cycles, not for a game, but I appreciate you taking the time to explain. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you select every thing **Mesh** objects, **Lights**, **Camera** etc then open the **Object menu** you will find that the **Join** option has been greyed out, and it wont appear in the search either.

[image]

If you select only the **Mesh** objects then you can use the **Join** function and Join operation will appear in the Search.

[image]

Comment: Selecting pieces one by one in the hierarchy worked; previously, I had deselected everything, went to wireframe and box selected all the lighthouse pieces and nothing else. Box selecting left the 'Join' command greyed out, but using your method of hierarchy selection made 'Join' active. Weird. Thanks very much, 3fingeredfrog.

Comment: Just mentioning this because if i remember correctly in an earlier post you mentioned that you intended using this lighthouse model in an external game engine? If so then i would guess you need to fix your railings because they are only one sided ! The railings will appear transparent when viewing the lighthouse from the exterier. i'll post some screenshots just in case face normals are  new to you :)

Comment: Is there a way to automatically select only meshes if it's hard to select everything one by one?